# Why white-space works different on Internet Explorer charts using Chartist?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, chartist.js

I am using Chartist to do some charts. I am not so good on css. On Internet Explorer the text on the label is shown always in one line, the wraping is not working. On Chrome and Firefox the text is wraped as the css says.

CSS:

```
.ct-label.ct-vertical.ct-start {
      white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Internet Explorer 11:

[image: IE]

Chrome:

[image]

Is there a way to make the "white-space: normal;" work on Internet Explorer?
Is there a workaround for this? For example, add some break lines on the white spaces? I already tried 
, \n and %0D%0A with no luck.

This is the code of the second chart (the middle one):

```
    <script>
        new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart02', {
          labels: ['CONDUCTOR FORESTAL','OPERARIO FORESTAL','OPERADOR MAQUINARIA','PROTECCION CONTRA INCENDIOS','OPERARIO INDUSTRIAL','JEFE BRIGADA','OPERADOR MAQUINARIA CAMINOS','JEFE FAENA','OPERADOR MAQUINARIA PESADA','CONTROL PRODUCCIÓN','SUPERVISOR','JEFE LINEA'],
          series: [
            [8358,4223,1625,390,333,308,128,51,42,27,3,1]   
          ]
        }, {
          seriesBarDistance: 10,
          reverseData: true,
          horizontalBars: true,
          axisY: {
            offset: 100
          },
          chartPadding: {
            right: 40,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 20
          }
    });
    </script>
```

I don't know what other code is relevant to post.

Comment: word-break is not what I want but neither is working on IE.

Comment: The [property white-space isnt supported on IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=white-space) Have you looked to see if there is a related (child or parent) element that may be causing the text to not wrap? Is there a CSS file being used?

Comment: I have "white-space: normal !important;" after the css files used and is working OK on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: yes I understand that. What I am saying is white-space is not supported by IE so using that CSS wont work for IE browsers which is why you dont see it wrapping. There is probably another class that is causing the text to not wrap (one that IE understands) that you should try and find so you can overwrite or change it.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I could not find any other class compatible with IE so I just abbreviated the labels.

Comment: If you add your CSS I will take a look at it. One other thing I was thinking was there is an old school HTML tag <nobr> that you might want to look out for as well.